# Writing a 3-band image with rasterio

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I would like to save a 3-band raster to file using [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio).

The official docs have examples for saving a single band image in both the [quickstart](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#saving-raster-data) and in the [advanced topics](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/writing.html#writing-datasets).

What I would like to do is something like..

```
with rasterio.open('image.tif', 'w', **meta) as dst:
    dst.write(array)
```

This raises the following error for an array with a shape of (256, 256, 3).

```
ValueError: Source shape (256, 256, 3) is inconsistent with given indexes 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numpy array needs to be in bands, rows, cols order (z, y, x) not cols, rows, bands (x, y, z).

You can rearrange the axes with [`numpy.moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html)

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio

with rasterio.open('image.tif', 'w', **meta) as dst:
    # If array is in (x, y, z) order (cols, rows, bands)
    dst.write(np.moveaxis(array, [0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 0]))

    # If array is in (y, x, z) order (rows, cols, bands)
    dst.write(np.moveaxis(array, [0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1]))  # same as np.rollaxis(array, axis=2)
```

Comment: how do you change the order?

Comment: @Emtomp, see answer below

Answer (score 8):

To rearrange the axis (i.e., move the bands channel to make it the first axis), you can use [`np.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html).

```
with rasterio.open('image.tif', 'w', **meta) as dst:
    # Note: assumes band info is in axis 2. Also, break up commands for clarity.
    rolled_array = np.rollaxis(array, axis=2)  # Roll axis 2 to 0th position
    dst.write(rolled_array)
```

---

`rasterio` also has some built-in function to help with this [as shown here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/image_processing.html#image-processing-software). See `rasterio.plot.reshape_as_raster` and `rasterio.plot.reshape_as_image`.

Comment: `np.rollaxis` won't work if `array` is in `(x, y, z)` order, you'll end up with `(z, x, y)` instead of `(z, y, x)`.